# Why is page/2/ not working?

Tags: permalinks, pagination

[image]

This is my search page code can anyone help me figure out what is the problem I m having no content in my page 2

```
            <div class="<?php echo esc_attr($blog_type);?>">
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- Blog Archive -->
                    <div class="posts-masonry">
                        <!-- Blog Post-->
                        <?php get_template_part('template-parts/layouts/blog', 'loop');?>                       
                    </div>
                    <!-- Pagination -->  
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                        <?php adforest_pagination();?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Right Sidebar -->
            <?php
            if (isset($adforest_theme['blog_sidebar']) && $adforest_theme['blog_sidebar'] == 'right')
                get_sidebar();

            if (!isset($adforest_theme['blog_sidebar']))
                get_sidebar();
            ?>
            <!-- Middle Content Area  End -->
        </div>
        <!-- Row End -->
    </div>
    <!-- Main Container End -->
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add this as a comment but cant right now.
Im not seeing `<?php get_search_form(); ?>` 
Also, your code is not complete...you are showing a closing section tag but not the opening one. Also, you are searching page/2, this looks like a menu item. If this exact wording is not in the content area, then Im pretty sure you will not see any results. Go see this for info: https://wordpress.org/support/article/creating-a-search-page